# How I get the location and dimensions of a UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uitoolbar

One of those things that is probably trivial when you know the magic, which I don't.  I want to know the x,y location and dimensions of the `UIToolbar` at the bottom of my iPhone screen (so that I can make sure whatever I do in the window above it, which is a video preview window, doesn't over lap the toolbar).  But toolbars don't have a frame, so what to do?

I create the toolbar in the Storyboard and then drag a line over to .h file which creates this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIToolbar) NSArray *mainToolBar;
```

So how do I go from this `NSArray` to something with a frame?  Please note that I want this information on the toolbar itself, not the buttons within.

Thank you very much.

PS - I recognize that the toolbar is below the preview window and so it doesn't strictly apply in this case, but I'd like to know the answer for other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your outlet from here

[image]

Instead of creating from

[image]

And access your frame property

```
float y =  self.toolbar.frame.origin.y; like this
```

Comment: Thank you.  My mistake was that I linked from the outlet collection not from the outlet.  I knew it would be simple...
Thanks again.